esrally tool process Doesn't Exit and No Report Generated After All Operations Complete
I'm encountering a recurring issue where, after all operations have been completed, the process doesn't exit as expected and no report is generated. This issue is significantly affecting my work. Could anyone provide some guidance on this? Thank you in advance.
detail issue reference:  https://github.com/elastic/rally/issues/1856

Ideally [mre] inside your post, with the link only as supporting information, as recommended in [ask]

If your MCVE is still somewhat large, is it OK to post a link to github? - Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?
